# suspending an azure virtual network?

Tags: azure, networking, vpn, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to suspend an Azure Virtual Network Gateway the same way it's possible to suspend a server?  I cannot find any place to do a suspension.  I can only delete the network.  It took some time to set up so I'd love to save the configuration even if I wish to suspend the network.

Thanks!

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to suspend a virtual network gateway. The only option you have is to delete it and recreate it.

It is possible to script the both sides of the process so it could be automated reasonably easily. Although you would end up with different end points, but you could resolve that by pointing your own DNS to them.

Answer (score 0):

The option to "Stop" & "Start" is currently unavailable from the VPN gateway perspective.
Which you would have to delete and re-create. Either which ways the Public IP would change and only benefit would be from the cost incurred. Where you would be billed for compute and storage.

But, the Application Gateway has this if you are interested go on to resources.azure.com and search for your Application gateway under the valid subscription.

Note: This will change the Public IP which can't be recovered and also can't be made static.